# Retrieving yfrog images

Tags: image, imageshack, yfrog

Ever since yfrog stopped being yfrog and started changing to imgshack or whatever the name is, some of my pictures on my account linked to twitter don't show up. They just show a blank picture of a camera, like this: http://twitter.yfrog.com/h0tjfqlpj

My dog passed away recently and I know I have more pictures of her on there than just the ones that are still available. Is there a way that I can retrieve them, no way at all or should I just email yfrog?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/6296561)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happened to a lot of people. My best suggestion is to email is-support@imageshack.net (per [this page](https://imageshack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200826330-I-have-missing-or-broken-images)) and see if they can help you retrieve the images. Good luck, and many sympathies on your loss.